# Batch processing fails in Oracle. Find out which statement in the batch is causing it

Tags: java, database, oracle11g, relational-database, struts-1

I am extracting data from excel sheet and inserting them into my oracle table. The database is setup in a way that when executing a batch statement, if any insert statement in the batch fails, all the other statements in the batch are not executed. So my problem is how can I find out which row of data is actually causing it, so I can send a message to the user with the row number of the data that's causing the problem?

```
Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    Iterator iterator = list.iterator();
    int rowCount = list.size();
    int currentRow = 0;
    String sqlStatement = "INSERT INTO DMD_VOL_UPLOAD (ORIGIN, DESTINATION, DAY_OF_WEEK, VOLUME)";
    sqlStatement += " VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)";
int batchSize==1000;
for(currentRow=1; currentRow<=rowCount; currentRow++){
            ForecastBatch forecastBatch = (ForecastBatch)      iterator.next();                                 
            pstmt.setString(1, forecastBatch.getOrigin());
            pstmt.setString(2, forecastBatch.getDestination());
            pstmt.setInt(3, forecastBatch.getDayOfWeek());                                          
            pstmt.setInt(4, forecastBatch.getVolumeSum());

            pstmt.addBatch();
        if(i % batchSize == 0){
                updateCounts = pstmt.executeBatch();
                con.commit();
                pstmt.clearBatch();
                session.flush();
                session.clear();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`executeBatch` returns an integer array containing the counts of all the rows modified by each statement in the batch.  I think negative numbers are used to indicate errors.  You should be able to figure out which ones failed using this return value.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/guide/jdbc/spec2/jdbc2.1.frame6.html

Comment: thanks for response. I looked at that api.If my batch has 10 insert statements and the 5th one fails, all the other 9 fail as well. So the batch statement returns an array of 10 negative numbers because all of them failed. If my system or database was set up in such a way that it would continue to execute the rest of the statements in the batch even if one of them failed, then the returned array would have one negative number for the failed statement and +ve for the rest. And I would have been able to tell which statement failed. But that's not the case, if one fails, everything fails.

Comment: There may be some way of telling the batch to do as many as possible  before you execute it.  If not, you'll have to do binary search on the set of updates to find the one that breaks it...

Comment: Thanks Keith. Although I have resorted to making the batchSize=0, your answer has pointed me towards a direction I may explore in the future when I have more time.

Answer (score 1):

java.sql.Statement's javadoc says that `executeBatch()` throws `BatchUpdateException` (a subclass of SQLException) if one of the commands sent to the database fails to execute properly or attempts to return a result set.

The method `getUpdateCount()` of `java.sql.BatchUpdateException` "..Retrieves the update count for each update statement in the batch update that executed successfully before this exception occurred..."

If none of this works, you will probably have to fall back to executing and committing each statement (within this particular batch) individually until you hit an error.

Comment: It seems that I have to change the batch size to 1 and execute each insert statement at a time and commit it. But this leads to a huge performance hit. It took me about 5 minutes to finish executing. According to your solution, which sounds like a better option, my question is how would I know that this particular batch will give me an exception?

Comment: You're right, you wouldn't know it in advance. I was thinking you'll put a try/catch around your pstmt.executeBatch() that will be catching BatchUpdateException. In its catch block, backtrack your "i" counter (which I dont see how maintained in the code btw) and start executing the statements from i* to batchSize one at a time.